# check if time has passed since the creation of a timedate variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Time left is declare as time.now and I need to check if 10 minutes has passed since its creation. After the db has been checked it will delete all records that meet the criteria

```
              var orders = from o in db.Orders
                     where o.HasPaid = false && o.timeleft == o.timeleft + 10

        select o;
```

Comment: Well, this will never evaluate to true: `o.timeleft == o.timeleft + 10`

Comment: Look up DATEPART (SQL) or TimeSpans (C#).

Comment: yeah just noticed it should be something like if time.now is greater than 10 minutes away from o.timeleft

Comment: Also, this is an assignment, not a comparison: `o.HasPaid = false `

Answer (score 0):

You are checking to see if a field from the database is equal to itself plus `10`, which will never be true. It sounds like you stored `timeleft` when the order was placed, and it is 10 minutes later than the order date. If that's the case, do you mean something like this instead?

```
var overDueOrders = from o in db.Orders
                    where o.HasPaid == false && 
                    o.timeleft <= DateTime.Now
                    select o;
```